# Geocoding limit problems

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a page where the user has to select a place on the map. He can still search for it. 
While moving the marker I want him to know where "is he at" and that value is also stored in a hidden input, just like the latitude and longitude so It can later be used to insert the values in the database. 
Everything Works fine, except that after I inserted the geocoding feature (may be a coincidence) the searchbox does not work anyome. It shows the results, but when you click nothing happens. I tried removing the geocoding but still don't work.
I'm also getting OVER_QUERY_LIMIT.
Here's my code:

```
function initialize() {


    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 

  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-1.456688, -48.477586);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    minZoom: 13,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false
  };


  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'position_changed', function() {
    var lat = this.getPosition().lat();
    var lng = this.getPosition().lng();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    document.getElementById('latitude').value = lat;
    document.getElementById('longitude').value = lng;


geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    if (results[0]) {
       document.getElementById('enderec').value = results[0].formatted_address;
       $('.onde-esta').html(results[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      alert("Sem resultados");
    }
  } else {
    alert("Geocoder falhou: " + status);
  }
});

  });


  // Create an Autocomplete and link it to the UI element.
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ (
    document.getElementById('pac-input'));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);



  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (input), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });

  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'place_changed', function() {
        var place = this.getPlace();
       document.getElementById('enderecoo').value = place.formatted_address;
    //when place has been found
    if (place.geometry) {
      marker.setOptions({
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        marker.getMap().fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        marker.getMap().setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      }
    }

    else {
      marker.setOptions({
        title: null
      });
      alert('Lugar não encontrado');
    }
  });

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
  // current map's viewport.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Is it because everytime the user moves the marker it geocodes? Is there anyway I can make it geocode only when the user DROPS the marker?
Thanks in advance,
Mateus

Answer (score 1):

Yup. I think you're hitting too much or too fast the geocode api. Try using it only when the use drop the marker.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, "dragend", function(event) { 
     /*
         User stopped dragging.
     */ 
    });
```